# How do decide whether 5^n o, Θ, or ω of 7^n?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o, little-o

As a homework problem, I need to decide whether 5<sup>n</sup> is little-o, Θ, or little-ω of 7<sup>n</sup> with mathematical justification. I then need to repeat this after taking the logarithms of both sides.

I am struggling to understand what I am being asked to do. The best guess I have is saying A(n) = 5<sup>n</sup> and B(n) = 7<sup>n</sup> then using l'Hopital's rule but I am unsure of how to proceed.  I'm just looking for a kick in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One formal definition of little-o notation is

> f(n) = o(g(n)) iff lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> f(n) / g(n) = 0

As a hint, note that

> 5<sup>n</sup> / 7<sup>n</sup> = (5 / 7)<sup>n</sup>

What happens if you take the limit as n goes to infinity?

If you take the logs of both sides, you get

- log 5<sup>n</sup> = n log 5
- log 7<sup>n</sup> = n log 7

How are these functions related to one another?  Could you prove it?

Hope this helps!